# Old UI on a Newer Airflow Version?

Tags: user-interface, graph, airflow

I've switched from v2.1.2 to the Airflow v2.7.3, and I do not find the new graph view UI to be an improvement.
I'm wondering if there's a way to use the newer version, but with the older version of the graph view UI?

Airflow v2.1.2 --> v2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

## Preface

The OP seeks to use old graph view in 2.7+.  While that would be nice, the best I have done so far is to try to add one "lost" feature (full task names) into the new graph view.

## Incomplete hack

Below, we apply local CSS to get "full task names" shown to the best ability possible.  The approach is by editing the local CSS for the text of one node to "wrap" and to be "smaller".  With this, full task names can fit somewhat reasonably:

```
/* Apply CSS selecting the text element containing the task name */
.c-12ug5cw {
  --chakra-line-clamp: 3 !important; /* wrap instead of truncate */
  font-size: 60% !important; /* to make all text basically fit */
}
```

## Inadequacies

While it is a start, this is far from done or perfect.

- It does not even work in Stylus for applying to all nodes automatically nor for persisting across page refreshes.
- (It only works by editing the HTML in the browser, which is not good enough to be useful.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know what the Community Bot doesn't understand; in my view, the Preface very clearly addresses its question specifically.

Comment: Related, it looks like https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/37254 will implement line wrapping (and wider nodes where useful) in order to help support longer task name display in the new graph view.